# Is there a way to accept array of objects with any number of fields and any type but one required field, not using the "any" type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The function `printNames` must accept an array of objects, that have a required field `name` and any other fields.

I can't use `any`

I can't change `IName`

```
interface IName {
    name: string
}

const printNames = (items: Array<Combine<IName, { [key: string]: any }>>) => {
    items.forEach(item => console.log(item.name));
}

printNames([{ name: 'ook' }]);
printNames([{ age: 2, name: 'ook' }]);
printNames([{ lastName: 'test', name: 'ook' }]);
```

I guess I should make use of generics somehow, but have no idea how.

Comment: `items: IName[]`? TS will just ignore any extra props.

Comment: this will cause errors on compilation:
Type '{ lastName: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IName'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'lastName' does not exist in type 'IName'.

Comment: That's only because that's what you're using in the example. In practical usage, or if you type those values *other than* by passing them, it's fine.

Comment: Even just with type inferred through assignment, for example: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDk4FsUG8BQyyI2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3PgL774ID2I1yADreEw5kAXmQAKYJCyUKGUgG0AugEpRAPmRSIMgHQwOUAKKIAFuPG5ipZMzUjNnbhwA2EXS451xJHCpVM7Fw82jKiyApWvuTIAOQARnAkJLEANMhwdDEAjADMtkqB-KBgQhCS0pQB+EA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics and indicate that the generic type should implement `IName`.

```
const printNames = <T extends IName>(items: Array<T>) => {
    items.forEach(item => console.log(item.name));
}
```

Comment: That's only necessary where you're passing literals type *only* as parameters. Otherwise just `IName[]` works fine.